# Where and how to use Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate with Authorize.Net

Tags: php, authorize.net, applepay, applepayjs

While trying to add Apple Pay Web into one of my websites, I'm having a confusion on how to and where to use this Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate.

My Payment Processor is Authorize.net

And I followed their docs:
https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/in-app.html

I've followed all the steps and i have the certificate now. 
I've also achieved the Payment Token (nonce) from Apple.
But i don't find anywhere to use that above certificate.

Any advices here? Unfortunately there is unclear and few docs re apple pay web integration with authorize.net

Thx

Comment: as for other payment gateways, you need to upload that cert back to payment gateway

Comment: @BrianPham how did you get the token do you have any example i can use.

Comment: @BrianPham Please can you share me an email

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan pls make question

Answer (score 1):

When you try sandbox, you should login to your sandbox account in sandbox.authorize.net. Then go to "Digital payment solutions" -> ApplePay -> Sign In.
There you should add Your apple pay merchant ID (something like com.mycooldomain.app) to get payment process certificate request.

Go back to your apple developer account -> merchant identities -> Your merchant identity you used in auth.net -> Payment Processing Certificate -> Create.

Choose file and select your certificate request from auth.net. And that's it.

Comment: So you don't need to do anything with the actual certificate once you've generated it?

Comment: Well, you should use it if you want to decrypt applepay token, but mostly, you don't need that. You can send the encrypted token directly to your payment provider.

Comment: I have one question like from the apple documentation they saying like need to create "Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate" for the apple pay on web. I am also using authnet, so how we generate this. I already generated the payment processing certificate with the csr file got from authnet. But i dont know how to generate the merchant identity certificate. Any method for this?